# Android Studio show unhandled exceptions

Tags: android-studio

How can I see `errors` throwing from `unhandled exceptions` in **android studio**? In **ADT pulgin for Eclipse**, it shows these `errors` in `logcat`.

Answer (score 4):

In **Android Studio**  you can check the log cat by using shortcut `ALT+6` or click on `View` and than click `Tool Windows` and than click on `Android ( ALT+6 )` and now you can also use `logcat` in `android studio` and check all the `errors` .

Comment: What's the shortcut for that in Mac?